# access public variable in other script/scene

Tags: unity

I have public variable `score` in script `scr_a` that attach to object `obj_a` in scene `sce_a`.

now I need to access the variable (score) in script `scr_b` that attach to object `obj_b` in scene `sce_b`.

I have try something but they did not work and I think that's because my scripts are in two different scene...

Comment: If you load new scene Unity will destroy every object on prevoius scene. You can mark object to not be destroyed with `DontDestroyOnLoad()` method.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Game states & passing data between scenes](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117557/game-states-passing-data-between-scenes/), but it can not be marked as such because the answer is not upvoted or accepted.

Comment: @Philipp there, have an upvote. Does the duplicate flagging work now?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 yes, works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Score managing object that doesn't destroy in scene load or destroy. Unity have have a method `DontDestroyOnLoad()` for doing that. Get this object from other script with tag like "ScoreManager" then access the public methods as you need.

Use some code like below:

```
private int score;

void Awake()
{
 DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}

public int GetCurrentScore()//call this method to get the current score
{
 return score;
}

public void UpdateScore()//call this method to update the score increment
{
 score++;
}
```

Comment: This would need more to act as a score manager. I generally use a static self reference, given that management scripts shouldn't have multiple instances running at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You have to maintain/retain/dontDestory **scr_a** script when you switching from **sce_a** to **sce_b** and this can be acheiveable through this

```
public scr_a{
public int score;
 void Awake() {
        Debug.Log("DontDestory Script's Awake");
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }
///your logic update or blah blah functions

}
```

Adding [DontDestoryOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in your scr_a script will maintain you scr_a script object in sce_b then you can get it in scr_b using this

```
scr_a scr_aObj = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<scr_a>();
Debug.Log(scr_aObj.score);
```

Comment: @Timelord64 Hi... I fixed the first error. but how can i fix second error? thanks...

Comment: @Timelord64 Oops... i know that... actaully i think that was an accident

Comment: @mmoj what is the error ?

Comment: @Timelord64 whats wrong in the code, it is untested code giving the accurate concept.

Comment: There are two methods for finding an object as you describe. `Object.FindObjectOfType<Type>()` and `Object.FindObjectOfType()`. In your example, your using the method `Object.FindObjectOfType<>(scr_1)`, which as I said, gives you two seperate errors from bad overloading. Even in the case of the later, you still need to cast the return for it to work. It is always best to test code you have not used before, or are unfamiliar with, as even minor discrepancies like this will cause fatal errors. In this example, you do not even need to run the code before the compiler should report errors.

Comment: Note that I say `Object.FindObjectOfType` because that is the actual function. `GameObject` inherets it from `Object`. [You can find the API reference for `Object.FindObjectOfType()` here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html).

Comment: @Timelord64 Thanks but we dont have time to run code, its take much time to create scenario. it is better that if you find error in answer then, update it

Comment: @mmoj answer updated hope it will work now