# How to deal with data transfer between scenes

Tags: unity, scene, scenemanager

What i would like to achieve is to have 1 global 2d map where armies could move (Scene 1). When they collide, trigger loads new scene, setup parameters like army size etc (Scene 2). Once battle is finished, I would like to close scene2 and load again scene1.
I implemented this and had bad feelings about setting up Scene 1 into the same position as i left it(I used singletos for this).
Wouldnt it be better approach to hide Scene1, so all data will be consistent and once scene 2 is finished, show it again? Is it possible and is it good idea?

Another way I was thinking about was to create scene3 which would contain all important data needed for scene1 setup. So when I move from scene1 to scene2, i can destroy scene1. Once I finish scene2, I would start scene 1, which has its data inside scene 3 so scene setup would be done out of the box without defining some special scene init scripts.

Honestly I could not fight any proper solution for scene management, only tons of basic tutorials

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+between+scenes) and found [existing answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/117558/39518) about [ways to do this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/110963/39518). What specific problem have you encountered putting these solutions into practice?

Comment: I did already read those questions before i asked new one and also I did already test those methods, but it seems to me that this helps only if you would like to transfer some smaller data, not whole scene setting which could contain 300 parameters on different objects. 
The main question was if it is good idea to hide scene/have important data in 3rd scene

Comment: Did you test it, and did it work? If it works, it's a "good enough" idea to get the job done. If it didn't work, then ask about how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, so should I be using "it works" sollution instead of best one for me and after 3 months scrap whole game coz I used bad pattern?

Comment: If you can't see 3 months into the future, neither can we. There are very few cases in game development where there's a universally-agreed "best" solution. So "does it work?" is often our best guide. Is there a particular problem with your approach that you're worried will break in 3 months, that we can help you solve proactively?

Comment: Have you looked into loading scenes [additive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html)?

Comment: Most improvements to code come from the fact that the developer coded themselves in a corner. As DMGregory pointed out, if you see what situation you'll need to handle in the future, prototype it now.

Comment: @schneebuzz yes, I did it is actually I was talking about usage of additive scene in my question. But still thank you

Comment: Thank you boys, it was so helpful for me to listen your advices. 
I already know my situation, I see possible problem, and I did spend a lot of time searching for possible sollutions. I proposed 2 and i am asking if anyone who has experience with such thing could tell me if it is totally bad idea, good one if if there is way better sollution.
In the past it happened several times to me that I messed up architecture and than I spend a lot of time fixing it. So now I am trying not to make the same  mistake.